# Create a pdf for each selected Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create separate PDFs for each sheet in a selection of sheets, with a name determined by the sheet name and the contents of one cell.

The code is as follows:

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsPDFs()
    Dim sFile       As String
    Dim sPath       As String
    Dim sh          As Object
    Dim InvDate     As String

    With ActiveWorkbook

        sPath = .Path & "\"
        For Each sh In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

            InvDate = Format(Range("G9"), "dd-mm-yy")
            sFile = sh.Name & " - Invoice - " & InvDate & ".pdf"
            sh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                   Filename:=sPath & sFile, _
                                   Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                   IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                                   IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                   OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Next sh
    End With
End Sub
```

Separate PDFs are created and named correctly, however, the PDF contains all the selected sheets instead of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With my experience, i've seen that the `ExportAsFixedFormat` always exports all selected sheets.

You can come around this by saying `sh.Select` after your `For Each`, and then it should works as you describe in the OP.

Edited code:

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsPDFs()
    Dim sFile       As String
    Dim sPath       As String
    Dim sh          As Object
    Dim InvDate     As String


    With ActiveWorkbook

        sPath = .Path & "\"
        For Each sh In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
            sh.Select '<----- New LINE

            InvDate = Format(Range("G9"), "dd-mm-yy")
                sFile = sh.Name & " - Invoice - " & InvDate & ".pdf"
                sh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                        Filename:=sPath & sFile, _
                                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                        IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
                                        OpenAfterPublish:=False
        Next sh
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you achive your goal. :)